# OnPause and return button

Tags: android

I have onPause in activity and works great. This is code

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Intent intent;

    intent = new Intent(Games.this, PauseScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

But I have a problem. When I push the back button onPause is calling and start new activity. I want to onPause works always except when I click back button on my phone. How I can do this? I think that may be `if(backbutton was click){onPause is not working}else{onPause working}` but I don't know how implement this solution. Or maybe you have better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user1302569

Here are step you can follow to achieve your desire behavior in Application..

STEP 1:  Overide this back Key method in your Activty.

```
@Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
             //Here you get Back Key Press So make boolean false
             no_back_key=false;
             super.onBackPressed();
}
```

STEP 2: Take One boolean variable like below in your Activity Class.

```
 public boolean no_back_key=true;
```

STEP 3: in your OnPause Method do some thing like Below

```
           @Override
           protected void onPause() {
           super.onPause();
           Intent intent;
           //Only this boolean will become false when we get Back Key Press as you Said in Your   Question
           if(no_back_key){
           intent = new Intent(Games.this, PauseScreen.class);
           startActivity(intent);
    }
```

STEP 4: in Your Activity's OnResume Make sure this also.

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    no_back_key=true;
    super.onResume();
}
```

}

Regarding Back Key Event in Android ,in Developer site you can refer this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `onBackPressed()` setting a flag in there and checking that flag in your `onPause()`

(It is strange though to start another activity from onPause but maybe you have good reasons to do so I can't think of such a scenario though...)

Answer (score -1):

Implement the following method-

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
             //Do something (OR NOTHING)
    }
    return true;
}
```

Remember to return `true` since it means that, you've handled on back key press and system does not need to handle it.

This is a good substitute for `onBackPressed()` which may or may not work for you.